# SQL Server sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to combine 2 SQL queries, the first query i want to pull back employee records for the latest month, and the second query, pull back records for the last 3 months.

There is a method to the madness, employees can change manager each month, but the latest months manager needs to see the previous 3 month records for their employee, even if that employee had a different manager for those months.

This is the 1st select to pull in latest month

```
/******latest month*****************/
SELECT [REPORT_DT]
      ,[EMPLOYEE_ID]
      ,[EMPLOYEE_NAME]
      ,[LOCATION]
      ,[JOB_DESCRIPTION]
      ,[MANAGER_ID]
  FROM [EMPLOYEE]
  where [REPORT_DT]=
  (select max([REPORT_DT]) from [EMPLOYEE])
```

this is the select to pull in last 3months

```
/*********last 3 months*******************/
SELECT [REPORT_DT]
      ,[EMPLOYEE_ID]
      ,[EMPLOYEE_NAME]
      ,[LOCATION]
      ,[JOB_DESCRIPTION]
      ,[MANAGER_ID]
  FROM [EMPLOYEE]
  where [REPORT_DT]>=
  ( DATEADD(M, -3, GETDATE()))
```

i would be joining the 2 selects on [EMPLOYEE_ID]. Any ideas how i can combined these 2 querys?
Thanks!

Comment: Combine how? You can AND or OR the where clause conditions.

Comment: Presumably, the latest month is one of the last three months, so the second query encompasses the first query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join the two tables, you would use:

```
select ecurr.*, e.*  -- or whatever columns you like
from employee ecurr join
     employee e
     on ecurr.employee_id = e.employee_id
where ecurr.report_dt = (select max(e2.report_dt) from employee e2) and
      e.report_dt >= dateadd(month, 3, getdate())
order by ecurr.employee_id, e.report_dt;
```

I will add that this result doesn't make particular sense to me.  But this is the question that you specifically asked.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed Gordon! Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: I have a follow up question on this. If I want to look at a previous month, and pull back the last 3 months from it, is there a way to alter the query to do this? So at the moment the latest report_dt is september, but if i run this query when looking at the august report_dt no data returns as september is the latest month.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
    [REPORT_DT],
    [EMPLOYEE_ID],
    [EMPLOYEE_NAME],
    [LOCATION],
    [JOB_DESCRIPTION],
    [MANAGER_ID],
FROM [EMPLOYEE]
WHERE
    [REPORT_DT] >= DATEADD(M, -3, GETDATE()
ORDER BY
    [REPORT_DT] DESC;
```

The above `WHERE` clause matches your second query, and we use a `TOP 1 WITH TIES` approach to obtain the records having the maximum `REPORT_DT` values in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT [REPORT_DT]
      ,[EMPLOYEE_ID]
      ,[EMPLOYEE_NAME]
      ,[LOCATION]
      ,[JOB_DESCRIPTION]
      ,[MANAGER_ID]
FROM [EMPLOYEE]
WHERE [REPORT_DT] = (SELECT MAX([REPORT_DT]) FROM [EMPLOYEE]) AND
      EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM [EMPLOYEE]
              WHERE [EMPLOYEE_ID] == t.[EMPLOYEE_ID] AND
                    [REPORT_DT] >= (DATEADD(M, -3, GETDATE())))
```

Regarding comment, this query should solve the problem:

```
SELECT [REPORT_DT]
      ,[EMPLOYEE_ID]
      ,[EMPLOYEE_NAME]
      ,[LOCATION]
      ,[JOB_DESCRIPTION]
      ,[MANAGER_ID]
FROM [EMPLOYEE]
WHERE [REPORT_DT] >= (DATEADD(M, -3, GETDATE())) AND
      EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM [EMPLOYEE]
              WHERE [EMPLOYEE_ID] == t.[EMPLOYEE_ID] AND
                    [REPORT_DT] >= (DATEADD(M, -1, GETDATE())))
```

Comment: This is returning data for the latest month, but i wanted to get a 3 month view of the data, with the latest month manager able to view any of his employees data for the last 3 month. Maybe i'm going about it the wrong way

Comment: @Blowers Try another query :)

Comment: @Blowers Remember to accept answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you want to get [EMPLOYEE_ID] list for the latest month. And get their 3 month work history. According to your current select scripts (I did not understand your first select script if it gives a employee list or not)  you can do like this. But it is not an effective solution. You can also add sub selection in the join section. First try this please.

```
SELECT [REPORT_DT]
      ,[EMPLOYEE_ID]
      ,[EMPLOYEE_NAME]
      ,[LOCATION]
      ,[JOB_DESCRIPTION]
      ,[MANAGER_ID]
  FROM [EMPLOYEE]
  where [REPORT_DT]>=(DATEADD(M, -3, GETDATE()))
AND [EMPLOYEE_ID] IN (SELECT [REPORT_DT]
      ,[EMPLOYEE_ID]
      ,[EMPLOYEE_NAME]
      ,[LOCATION]
      ,[JOB_DESCRIPTION]
      ,[MANAGER_ID]
  FROM [EMPLOYEE]
  where [REPORT_DT]=
  (select max([REPORT_DT]) from [EMPLOYEE]))
```

Comment: I get the following error when trying this query; Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Then try with exists;
SELECT [REPORT_DT]
      ,[EMPLOYEE_ID]
      ,[EMPLOYEE_NAME]
      ,[LOCATION]
      ,[JOB_DESCRIPTION]
      ,[MANAGER_ID]
FROM [EMPLOYEE]
WHERE [REPORT_DT] = (SELECT MAX([REPORT_DT]) FROM [EMPLOYEE]) AND
      EXISTS( SELECT [EMPLOYEE_ID] FROM [EMPLOYEE]
              WHERE [EMPLOYEE_ID] == t.[EMPLOYEE_ID] AND
                    [REPORT_DT] >= (DATEADD(M, -3, GETDATE())))

Answer (score 0):

I created a View using the below query, and then combined this with a 3 month date prompt (this is being used on a Business Objects report) and that did the trick.

```
SELECT 
b.[MANAGER_ID],
a.[EMPLOYEE_ID],
a.[START_DT],
a.[EMPLOYEE_NAME], 
a.[LOCATION],
a.[JOB_DESCRIPTION],
a.[REPORT_DT]
FROM  [EMPLOYEE] b INNER JOIN
      [EMPLOYEE] a
     ON b.[EMPLOYEE_ID] = a.[EMPLOYEE_ID]
WHERE b.[REPORT_DT] = (SELECT MAX(c.[REPORT_DT]) 
FROM [EMPLOYEE] c)
```